# separate words like tags php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, tags

I want to separate words from 1 line.

I tried this with my following code:

```
$tags = 'why,what,or,too,';
preg_match_all ("/,(.*),/U", $tags, $pat_array);
print $pat_array[0][0]." <br> ".$pat_array[0][1]."\n";
```

I want the result to resemble:

```
<img src="why.jpg"></br>
<img src="what.jpg"</br>
<img src="or.jpg"</br>
<img src="too.jpg"
```

I want to do like this site when you write a question you have to write 'Tags'.

Comment: see my answer. i think it is exactly you want

Answer (score 3):

```
    <?
    $tags = 'why,what,or,too,'; 
    $words = explode(',', $tags);
    ?>


    <?php foreach($words as $word) { 
    if(!empty($word))?>
    <img src="<?php echo $word;?>.jpg"></br>
    <?php } ?>
```

after exploding you will have an array

```
$words[0] = 'why';
$words[1] = 'what';
$words[2] = 'or';
$words[3] = 'too';
$words[4] = '';
```

Comment: <img src=".jpg"></br>
        <img src="why.jpg"></br>
        <img src="what.jpg"></br>
        <img src="or.jpg"></br>
        <img src="too.jpg"></br>
        <img src=".jpg"></br>
 its give me 2 img empty @bilal

Comment: have you place empty check?

Comment: `code`<?php foreach($words as $word) { 
    if(!empty($word))
    echo '<img src="'.$word.'.jpg"></br>
    } ?>`code`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `explode` function to split the input string by a given delimiter:

```
$tags = 'why,what,or,too,';
$array = explode(",", $tags);
```

Then iterate the array to display each tag:

```
foreach($array as $tag) {
    if(!empty($tag)) {
        echo "<img src=\"$tag.jpg\"></br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .. its give me this erorr

Comment: $tags was used in the loop, replace with $tags to $array, answer is also fixed

Answer (score 1):

Easy with explode

```
$tags = 'why,what,or,too,';
$array = explode(',',$tags );
echo '<pre>';
print_R($array);

<img src="<?php echo $array[0]?>"></br>
<img src="<?php echo $array[1]?>"></br>
<img src="<?php echo $array[2]?>"></br>
<img src="<?php echo $array[3]?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tags = 'why,what,or,too,';  
$temp = explode(",", $tags); // will return you array 

foreach($temp as $tag) {
  if(!empty($tag)
   echo "<img src=\"$tag.jpg\"></br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `explode` for this like it didn't print empty tag

```
 $tags = 'why,what,or,too,';
 $array=explode(",",$tags);
 $buf=array();
 foreach($array as $tag) {
    if(empty($tag))continue;
    $buf[]="<img src=\"$tag.jpg\">";
 }
 echo implode('</br>',$buf);
```

output

```
<img src="why.jpg"></br>
<img src="what.jpg"></br>
<img src="or.jpg"></br>
<img src="too.jpg">
```